# Why SQL Server imports badly my CSV file with bcp?

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I'm using bcp to insert a CSV file in my SQL table, but i'm having weird results.
All the environment is on Linux, I create the CSV file with IFS=\n in Bash. BCP is running from Bash too like this:

```
bcp Table1 in "./file.csv" -S server_name -U login_id-P password -d databse_name -c -t"," -r"0x0A"
```

The `file.csv` is about 50k rows. BCP tells me he copied 25K rows. No warnings, no errors. I have tried on a smaller sample with only 2 rows and here is the result:

`file.csv` data:

```
A.csv, A, B
C.csv, C, D
```

My table `Table1`:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    a VARCHAR(8),
    b VARCHAR(8),
    c VARCHAR(8)
    FOREIGN KEY (a) REFERENCES Table2(a)
);
```

`Table2` is a very basic table just like `Table1`

What I can see in Microsoft SQL Server Manager Studio when i do `SELECT * FROM Table1`

```
ID | a | b |     c       |
1    A   BC C.csv       E
```

I export with `bcp` like this:

```
bcp Table1 out"./file_export.csv" -S server_name -U login_id-P password -d databse_name -c -t"," -r"0x0A"
```

What I get in `file_export.csv`

```
1, A, B
C, C.csv, D, E
```

I've check on NotePad++ any strange End Of File, they are all `EF` (50k Rows) each values are separated by comas.

UPDATE:
Changing the options `-t` and `-r` does not change anything. So my CSV is well formatted. I think the issue the fact that I'm trying to import `x` columns in a tables of `x+1` fields (The auto-incremented `ID`).
So i'm using the simplest command for `bcp`

```
bcp Table1 in "./file.csv" -S server_name -U login_id-P password -d databse_name -c
```

Here is what i get in my `SELECT * FROM Table1;`
    ID a b      c
    1  A BC.csv C,D
Here is what I expected:

```
1,A.csv,A,B
2,C.csv,C,D
```

Why does my first field is "eaten" and replace by `1` (`ID`)? Which makes everything swift to the right.

Comment: *Why* did you change the row terminator? `\n` is [the default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/specify-field-and-row-terminators-sql-server). In any case, the feature that's used to load *and* transform data into SQL Server is SSIS, not bcp. `bcp` is meant for bulk import/export. The `Import Data Wizard` uses SSIS to import data, and allows you to *preview* it, and save the package for modification and reuse. Not that it matters in this case, you specified the letters `0`, `x` and `A` as the terminator

Comment: Because my CSV file is a merge of text files generated by .jar, i just wanted to be sure at 100% of the result. At first I didn't set `IFS`, I added it to be sure that `\n` or `0x0A` was not the source of the problem (at least what i think)

Comment: BTW CSVs aren't *simple* files, especially when they include newlines inside quoted fields. `bcp` added full CSV support, quirks and all on SQL Server 2017, available for download on Monday. Flat file import works perfectly for the last 20 years

Comment: instead of making sure, you *introduced* a problem. Do the fields contain newlines? Have you tried to import the file with the Import Wizard? You can preview the data and see how the different newline, delimiter choices affect it

Comment: Ok, maybe the problem is the -r"0x0A", but when i don't use it, it gives me the same out-put by export or SSMS

Comment: On the other hand if the *file* has mixed up separators, bcp can't import it.

Comment: Export? SSMS? What does that have to do with *bcp*?

Comment: I never tried with a Wizzard, you have any suggestion? (I'm used to do everything with command lines) I already have a functional project with MYSQL and I don't have any problem with the return line

Comment: And what do you mean `IFS`? Googling for `bcp IFS` returns only *this* question. There's no such flag

Comment: It's not a flag, i just that that my `IFS` was set to `\n` in the creation of the CSV file. Nothing to do with `bcp`

Comment: Right click on the database node, select `Import Data ...`. You can create complex packages with SQL Server Data Tools that read, transform, convert, merge data on the fly. The wizard creates a simple import package

Comment: I can't find any `Import Data` or even `Export` in my SSMS, on the node or even on the top options...

Comment: *All* the tasks, including backup, restore, Import, Export,  are under the `Tasks` submenu. [Check here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/start-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard).

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. I have found it. So now I chose a `Flat File` Source. with line separator `{LF}` and column `Comma {,}`. The preview is good like I want. So i guess my `bcp`...`in` is wrong. I've tried to change `-t","` by `-t ","`, `-t,`, `-t ,` or `-r"0x0A"` with  `-r"\n"`,  `-r \n` still not working. I tried also without `-r` and `t` and the import of `Tables1` is wrong but `table2` is good. The only difference between them is that `Table1` adds a new column `ID` whereas `Table2` don't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155604/discussion-between-begreen-and-panagiotis-kanavos).